# how to use java to read array to vtkImageData

Tags: java, c++, 3d, vtk

I would like to use java to virtualize a 3D array. However, there is not too much demo code using java, so I take some C++ demo code for example.Here is an example using C++ that implements 3D Reconstruction of 3D array data in memory which represents 3D Image. First, it creates a 3D array in memory, like this:

```
unsigned short data[dim][dim][dim];

for (int i=0;i<dim;i++)

for (int j=0;j<dim;j++)

for (int k=0;k<dim;k++)

   data[i][j][k]=1000;
```

and then transfer this array's pointer to vtkImageData which can process the 3D array data later, like this:

```
vtkUnsignedShortArray *array=vtkUnsignedShortArray::New();

array->SetVoidArray(data,dim*dim*dim,1);


vtkImageData *imageData=vtkImageData::New();

imageData->GetPointData()->SetScalars(array);
```

according to this procedure, I write a similar code using java, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXSSE.png)

but I can't find a suitable way to transfer my 3D image data array(`imageArr` which read pixel data from a specified tiff file).

Here my problem, how can I reconstruct 3D iamge data array to 3D image using java based on vtk.

I am Chinese student and not good at using English, I will be very exited for your reply.